# Where do I put the code for changing the nav bar color in xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uicolor, navigationbar, tintcolor

Ok, it's 3 am atm and I haven't a clue where I put this:

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor];
```

If you would please post the whole .m/.h files that would be great. Also, do I connect anything using segues or outlets? And when you create the .h/.m files do I need  UINavigationController or similar selected or just the normal UIViewController? Thanks.

Update: Nevermind I got it, thanks though. Below is the code for others having my issue.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];

    [bar setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}
```

Basically just add on to what's already there.
I feel stupid lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that value right after you `init` your `UINavigationController`, i.e:

```
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINabvigationController alloc] initWithRoot...
[controller.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Ok, but where do I put this at?